# How to use incoming Binance WebSocket data?

Tags: javascript, websocket, axios, binance

My question is how can I make use of WebSocket data in general. im using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance to get binance live tickers. what i want to do is take that live data and compare it to some other exchanges data which im calling using axios. but all i get is continous stream of binance data and donno how to make use of it, i am trying to run function inside the `stream` but that does not seem to help as the data stream is continuous and axios request takes time to return. i can add more if my question is incomplete.

Comment: What is your goal? To compare prices on several exchanges at the same moment? How much precission do you need? (e.g. 1 second diff is ok or not?) ... What is your reason to use a combination of WSS (Binance) and REST (other sources) instead of just WSS or REST for all sources?

Comment: @PetrHejda my goal is to compare prices. yea, i want to compare with only one exchange. 5-10 seconds is okay. because the other exchange doesn't have WebSocket api https://github.com/WazirX/wazirx-api.

Comment: @PetrHejda im using this for binance https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance

Answer (score 0):

The [binance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance) package only supports websocket streams, but REST API (either [directly](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) or using a [different](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance-api-node) package) will help you achieve your goal more easily.

You can have two functions - each for retrieving price form the exchange, and then compare the price from the different sources.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getBinanceBtcPrice = async () => {
    // binance allows retrieving a single symbol
    // if you omit the param, it would return prices of all symbols
    // and you'd have to loop through them like in the WazirX example
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSDT');
    return response.data.price;
}

const getWazirxBtcPrice = async () => {
    // WazirX only returns all symbol data
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status');

    // you need to loop through all of them, until you find the desired pair
    for (let market of response.data.markets) {
        // in your case `btc` and `usdt` (mind the lowecase letters)
        if (market.baseMarket === 'btc' && market.quoteMarket === 'usdt') {
            // mind that WazirX only returns price in full integer,
            // it does not return floating numbers
            return market.last;
        }
    }

    // did not find the combination
    return null;
}

const run = async () => {
    const binancePrice = await getBinanceBtcPrice();
    const wazirxPrice = await getWazirxBtcPrice();

    console.log(binancePrice);
    console.log(wazirxPrice);
}

run();
```

Comment: yes, i tried this approach but the binance all tickers endpoint has 40 weight https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics
.i tried this and got a temp ban after sending few requests. this can work when comparing only one symbol but how can i scale it lets say around 20-30 tickers.

Comment: You can also use the "all tickers" endpoint, but **cache** your results if you want to lower the risk of being rate limited. Under 40 symbols, it might be still sufficient to use the N separate requests per symbol, since they have only 1 weight each. Mind the other rate limits, such as number of requests per second or per minute, and mind that it's going to take longer time to receive all responses compared to the one big request.

Comment: ill try to use the rest endpoint. this time with less number of requests per minutes so that I don't exceed the weight assigned. yea, ill use the all tickers endpoint. thanks petr for taking time and answering my question